# What is the probability that the person surveyed is male and a democrat?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There were $295$ people surveyed. Of those $295$ people, $141$ were male, and $21$ were democrats. There was a total of $75$ democrats. What is the probability that the person surveyed is both male and a democrat? I thought it would be $$\frac{141}{295} \times \frac{21}{75}$$ but that was not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be simpler than you think. The question states that within the 141 males, 21 were democrats. The probability of randomly selecting someone who is both male and a democrat is simply the number of those with that property (21) divided by total number of possible selections (295). 
$$P(\text{male and democrat}) = \frac{21 \text{ male democrats}}{295 \text{ surveyed}}$$